# echo fork bomb in bash script without fork bombing myself

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a bash script that will use all the argument in the script call, which I know you can get with `"$@"`. Lets say I want to just echo all the arguments, and my bash script looks like

```
function echo_everything() {
  echo "$@"
}
```

Then I call it with a fork bomb `echo_everything :(){ :|:& };:` and expect it to just print out `:(){ :|:& };:`. What actually happens is the fork bomb goes off. Is there something I'm doing wrong here for getting all the parameters as a string without calling them?

Comment: FYI, `function foo() {` is mixing two different historical syntax forms in a way that's compatible with neither. Use either the legacy ksh `function foo {` or the POSIX-compliant `foo() {`, not the gratuitously-incompatible bastardization `function foo() {`. See also https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Answer (score 2):

Here's how your code is parsed :

1. there are four commands, because unquoted `|`, `&` and `;` are commands separators
2. The first one is `echo_everything :(){ :`, which leads to the invocation of `echo_everything` with  the expansion of two arguments `:(){` and `:`. Trying to expand `:(){` raises a syntax error, but that doesn't stop the rest of your code from executing. It is ended by `|`, so its (empty) standard output will be piped into the following command.
3. The second is `:`; if you previously defined the fork bomb in your shell, this triggers it. If you didn't, it calls the bash builtin `:` that does nothing in this context. It is ended by `&`, so it will be executed in the background.
4. The third is `}`, which is a syntax error. It is ended by `;`.
5. The fourth is `:`, which is yet another call to a command/function/alias named `:`, possibly your fork bomb.

I'm guessing you previously defined the fork bomb function (named `:`) in your shell, which explains why your code would trigger it. Testing in a new shell the command would just raise a syntax error (see [here](https://ideone.com/Z1jrSp)) and use the natively defined `:` command that does nothing.

But what you obviously want to do is to quote the fork bomb definition to prevent its interpretation by bash:

```
echo_everything ':(){ :|:& };:'
```